# In C, is it guaranteed that the array start address is smaller than the other elements' addresses?

Tags: c, arrays, language-lawyer

In other word when doing

```
index = &array[x] - &array[0];
```

Is it always guaranteed (per C standard) that &array[0] <= &array[x], or is it dependent on the compiler?
What are the C standard chapters relevant for this topic ?

Comment: At a guess  6.5.6:9

Comment: "&array[x] <= &array[0]"

ITYM >=.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The address ordering is guaranteed. The behaviour of relational operators is defined in [C11 6.5.8p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p5):

> [...] pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values. [...]

Thus `&array[x] >= &array[0]` is true always if `x` is the index of an element, or one greater than the maximum index. (And if `x` is not the index of an element, or one past the end of the actual array, then behaviour is undefined.)

But surprisingly the *difference* `&array[x] - &array[0]` is defined *only* when

- `x` is an actual index of an element or one greater than the maximum index in the array **and**
- **`x` is not greater than `PTRDIFF_MAX`**

as there is a peculiar corner case: [C11 6.5.6p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6) says that

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. **The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined.** In other words, if the expressions P and Q point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements of an array object, the expression (P)-(Q) has the value **i-j provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t`.**[...]

If the signed `ptrdiff_t` is of same width as the unsigned `size_t`, it is possible to have an array for which there exists an index `x` greater than `PTRDIFF_MAX`; then `&array[x] >= &array[0]` still, but `&array[x] - &array[0]` has completely undefined behaviour.

---

Here is a demonstration. My computer is x86-64 that runs 64-bit Ubuntu Linux, but it is also capable of running 32-bit programs. In 32-bit X86 Linux + GCC, `ptrdiff_t` is a 32-bit signed integer, and `size_t` is 32-bit unsigned integer. A program run in 64-bit Linux in 32-bit mode can easily allocate over 2G of memory with malloc, as the entire 4G address space is reserved for user mode.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t size = (size_t)PTRDIFF_MAX + 2;
    size_t x = (size_t)PTRDIFF_MAX + 1;
    char *array = malloc(size);
    if (! array) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    array[0] = 42;
    array[x] = 84;
    printf("&array[0]: %p\n", (void *)&array[0]);
    printf("&array[x]: %p\n", (void *)&array[x]);
    printf("&array[x] >= &array[0]: %d\n", &array[x] >= &array[0]);
    printf("&array[x] - &array[1]: %td\n", &array[x] - &array[1]);
    printf("&array[x] - &array[0]: %td\n", &array[x] - &array[0]);
    printf("(&array[x] - &array[0]) < 0: %d\n", (&array[x] - &array[0]) < 0);
}
```

Then compiled for 32-bit mode and run:

```
% gcc huge.c -m32 -Wall && ./a.out 
&array[0]: 0x77567008
&array[x]: 0xf7567008
&array[x] >= &array[0]: 1
&array[x] - &array[1]: 2147483647
&array[x] - &array[0]: -2147483648
(&array[x] - &array[0]) < 0: 1
```

The memory was allocated successfully, the starting address is at 0x77558008, `&array[x]` is at `0xf7504008`, `&array[x]` is greater than `&array[0]`. The difference `&array[x] - &array[1]` produced a positive result, whereas `&array[x] - &array[0]`, with its undefined behaviour, now produced a negative result!

Comment: @DavidBowling or my own stupidity for trying to be the FGITW

Comment: Was already the same in C99, and for completeness is still the same in C++17. I really hate DV without comments!

Comment: @SergeBallesta I got the dvs when I was fgitwing, so np :D

Answer (score 3):

First of all, FWIW, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6/P9, (*emphsis mine*)

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the **difference of the
>   subscripts** of the two array elements. [...]

So, you don't need to be bothered about the individual pointer *value* (positioning) itself. It's the *difference* that matters (i.e, something like `|a-b|`)

---

That said, if it has to come to the "comparison", ( usage of relational operators, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`), the standard says,

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the
>   address space of the objects pointed to. [....] If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, [...] and **pointers to array elements with larger subscript
>   values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values.** [....]

So, for a statement like `&array[x] <= &array[0]`, it will evaluate to `0` (**FALSY**), when `x > 0`.

<sub>[Thanks to the other answer by Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186386/2173917)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because `&array[x]` is defined to be equivalent to `array+x`.

[6.5.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
>   is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
>   definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
>   (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
>   binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
>   to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
>   E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

Answer (score 2):

The C11 standard *defines* the address difference between elements of an array as a number that depends on the relative (logical) order of the elements. As specified in the description of the [additive operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p9):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the
>   same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
>   **the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array
>   elements.** The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its
>   type (a signed integer type) is ptrdiff_t defined in the 
>   header. If the result is not representable in an object of that type,
>   the behavior is undefined. In other words, if the expressions P and Q
>   point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements of an array object,
>   the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i-j provided the value fits in an
>   object of type ptrdiff_t. Moreover, if the expression P points either
>   to an element of an array object or one past the last element of an
>   array object, and the expression Q points to the last element of the
>   same array object, the expression ((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value as
>   ((Q)-(P))+1 and as -((P)-((Q)+1)), and has the value zero if the
>   expression P points one past the last element of the array object,
>   even though the expression (Q)+1 does not point to an element of the
>   array object.

So the difference in your example is **defined** as `x - 0`.

Answer (score 2):

From the C11 specification (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (E)) §6.5.8/5:

> When two pointers are compared, ... If the objects pointed to are members of the same aggregate object, ... **and pointers to array elements with larger subscript values compare greater than pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values**.

That means that `&array[x] <= &array[0]` will be *false* unless `x` is equal to zero.

Comment: _**pointers to elements of the same array**_ If `x` is less than `0`, pointers are invalid and can not be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Given that traversing a array can also be achieve by incrementing a pointer, it would appear to be fairly fundamental that the absolute address of subsequent indexes increase.

```
char[] foobar;
char *foobarPtr = foobar;

foobar[0] == *foobarPtr++;
foobar[1] == *foobarPtr++;
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
index = &array[x] - &array[0];
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
index = (array+x) - (array+0)
```

because in C any array is desugared as pointer.

Now given the `pointer arithmetic` it will be rewritten as `index = x`

The relevant topics you can google for or search inside ISO9899 are `pointer arithmetic` and [desugaring arrays as pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar#Notable_examples).